# Bundle products add to cart issue

Tags: magento-1.7, php, addtocart, bundled-product, qty-increment

I'm developing a **bundle product** module for **magento 1.7**

The module is working as expected with bundle products, however, issue appears with standard Magento configurable products - once I select size (simple product) and add it to cart, it automatically doubles product quantity.

For example:

- if we have an Item 'X' in Size 'S' Qty = 1 : we will not be able to add it to the cart and there will be "The requested quantity for Item 'X' is not available"
- Although if we change Item 'X' in Size 'S' Qty = 2, but still adding Item 'X' in Size 'S' Qty = 1 to cart,  then we are able to cart and checkout this item (note!! at this step magento will create an invoice with correct qty = 1 and prices, but once order is placed, Magento back-end will remove qty=2 from db row)

I have extended Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart with following:

```
/**
 * Get request for product add to cart procedure
 *
 * @param   mixed $requestInfo
 * @return  Varien_Object
 */
protected function _getProductRequest($requestInfo)
{
    if ($requestInfo instanceof Varien_Object) {
        $request = $requestInfo;
    } 
    elseif (is_numeric($requestInfo)) {
        $request = new Varien_Object(array('qty' => $requestInfo));

    } 
    else {

         if(isset($requestInfo['bundle_has_custom_options'])){
            if(!empty($requestInfo['options'])){
                foreach($requestInfo['bundle_simple_custom_options'] as $id => $opt){
                    foreach($opt['options'] as $key => $o){
                        $opt['options'][$key] = $requestInfo['options'][$key];
                        $requestInfo['bundle_simple_custom_options'][$id] = $opt;
                    }
                }
            }
            unset($requestInfo['options']);
        }            
        $request = new Varien_Object($requestInfo);
    }

    if (!$request->hasQty()) {
        $request->setQty();
    }

    return $request;

}
```

Could it be that qty double comes because the system is adding qty=1 from extended bundle cart function and qty=1 from standard configurable cart function?

If any further info required, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Is difficult to say without knowing what your **bundle product** module does or whether it handles with **Qty**. Do you have some observer checking for such in any **add_to_cart** events?

I have seen that for bundles even when the **Qty** of the whole bundle is 0 in the product detail view, this get increased to 1 when you add it in cart.

You can debug this file to start with something:
`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`
check output here: `echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1`